# Why can't mount nfs server from client?

Tags: linux, centos, firewall, nfs, mount

Follow these two guides installed NFS server and client:

- https://www.howtoforge.com/nfs-server-and-client-on-centos-7
- https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/setting-up-an-nfs-server-and-client-on-centos-7/

Hosts:

- Server: 192.168.1.1
- Client: 192.168.1.2

## Server

Config `/etc/exports` on server:

```
[root@server ~]# cat /etc/exports 
/var/nfsshare    *(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
/home            *(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
/var/nfs         *(rw,sync,no_root_squash,no_all_squash)
```

Run:

```
[root@server ~]# exportfs -a
```

## Client

Then tried to mount server from client, got error:

```
[root@client ~]# mount -t nfs 192.168.1.1:/home /mnt/nfs/home/
mount.nfs: access denied by server while mounting 192.168.1.1:/home
```

However, I can see mount information from client:

```
[root@client ~]# showmount -e 192.168.1.1
Export list for 192.168.1.1:
/var/nfs      *
/home         *
/var/nfsshare *
```

---

What's wrong?

Comment: Did you restart the service after allowing acces in `/etc/exports`?

Comment: @rawmain i use exportfs -auvfs however i mean that either your chmod is wrong or the user which has not set by * try to access it without having the permission?